# Converting Int to a char* pointer

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert an integer to a char* pointer so I can properly send the argument into another function. Is there anyway to do this without atoi?

```
int number=2123, number2= 1233; 
char* arg[];

arg[0] = number;
arg[1] = number2;
```

**Sorry for not making things clear so basically I want the arg[0] to equal the string rep of the number, so that i can send it into a function like this: converted(char* arg);

i would change the parameter data type but it has to be that pointer to send in.

Comment: So, you want the arguments in arg[] to be string representations of the numbers, like "2123" and "1233" as above?

Comment: You are confused. Do you actually want to convert the number into its character representation (in which case you need something like sprintf())? Or does your function that takes char * know what to do with the address of an integer? Also, you need to allocate memory for arg[], and arg[0], and arg[1].

Comment: Why you can't use `atoi` in the first place?

Comment: ..becasue they are already integers?  This question needs clarification re. types, formats etc. before it gets closed as 'unclear'.

Comment: A reasonable way of handlig such things is to declare a struct type to hold two integers, or two strings, (char[32], say), or both, depending on what it is you want, (which is still unclear), load it up and pass its address, (assuming that it's lifetime does not need to exceed that of your scope above, else malloc it).

Comment: You don't want `atoi`.  You might want `itoa` (if it existed).  Or you can just use `snprintf`.

Comment: just updated what I wanted sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume that a pointer is always at least the same size as an integer (are there any exceptions to this?) you can safely convert integers to pointers and back with these macros:

```
#define INT2POINTER(a) ((char*)(intptr_t)(a))
#define POINTER2INT(a) ((int)(intptr_t)(a))
```

Or if that other function isn't your function, but a function that wants the integers as string you could use asprintf() like this:

```
asprintf(&arg[0],"%d",number);
asprintf(&arg[1],"%d",number2);
```

But asprintf is not posix standard so it might not be available on all systems. You could use sprintf() (or snprintf() so be on the safe side) instead, but then you need to calculate the string length first.

Answer (score 0):

> to convert an integer to a `char*` pointer so I can properly send the argument into another function.

Create a *string* representation of the number by calling a helper function with a `char` array via a *compound literal* to convert the number.  The string will be valid for the function and to the end of the block of code.  Adequate sizing of the string is important - leave that for a separate exercise.  Code here uses 41, enough for 128 bit `int`.  No need for a memory management via `malloc()/free()` for such a small buffer.

```
char *my_itoa(char *dest, int i) {
  sprintf(dest, "%d", i);
  return dest;
}

#define ITOA(n) my_itoa((char [41]) { 0 }, (n) )

int main(void) {
  int number=2123, number2= 1233;
  printf("<%s> <%s>\n",  ITOA(number),  ITOA(number2));
  printf("<%s> <%s> <%s>\n",  ITOA(INT_MIN),  ITOA(0),  ITOA(INT_MAX));
}
```

Output

```
<2123> <1233>
<-2147483648> <0> <2147483647>
```

Comment: *Please* call it `itoa`!

Comment: @SteveSummit .ekatsim a saw tahT.  Code amended.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the function you"re looking for:

```
char    *int_to_char(int nb)
{
  int   div;
  char  *str;
  int   i;
  int   size;
  int   sign;

  i = -1;
  sign = 1;
  size = get_int_lenght(nb);
  if (!(str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1))))
    return (NULL);
  if (nb < 0)
    {
      sign *= -1;
      nb *= -1;
    }
  if (nb == 0)
    {
      str[++i] = '0';
      str[i + 1] = 0;
      return (str);
    }
  while (nb > 0)
    {
      str[++i] = (nb % 10) + '0';
      nb /= 10;
    }
  if (sign < 0)
    str[++i] = '-';
  str[i + 1] = 0;
  return (my_revstr(str));
}
```

With revstr function:

```
char    *my_revstr(char *str)
{
  int   i;
  int   j;
  char  tmp;

  i = -1;
  j = strlen(str);
  while (++i < j)
    {
      tmp = str[i];
      str[i] = str[--j];
      str[j] = tmp;
    }
  return (str);
}
```

And get_int_lenght function:

```
int     get_int_lenght(int nb)
{
  int   size;

  size = 0;
  if (nb <= 0)
    {
      size++;
      nb *= -1;
    }
  while (nb > 0)
    {
      size++;
      nb /= 10;
    }
  return (size);
}
```

Comment: `while (nb > 0)` is a problem for negative `int` and for `0`.

Comment: This function allocates heap memory to hold the resulting string. That's not necessarily a bad thing, but it needs to be documented so the caller can free the memory and avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @KeithThompson you're right, but to develop in C you must know how to manage the memory, and it's not the topic.

Comment: Posted code does not compile (`sign` not declared).  `int_to_char(INT_MIN)` --> `""`.

Comment: Yeah forgot to declare the sign variable

Comment: Note that with `INT_MIN`, `nb *= -1;` is _undefined behavior_, yet usually that behaves as desired.

Comment: Why go to all that work?  Why not just call `snprintf`?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how works its function. I'm at Epitech and we are used to recoding everything ourselves O:) We are not lazy :D

Comment: @YaatSuka: You introduced the topic of memory management when you wrote a call to `malloc`. And I'd say that reinventing the wheel rather than learning how to use existing tools is a special kind of lazy. BTW, `nb *= -1` is better written as `nb = -nb`